# permission for using gmail account

Tags: gmail

I've developed a App, which sends and receives mails over google mail account with certain contents. Do I need for using that app the permission of google?

Answer (score 2):

No. You just need to use the appropriate pop servers. You application would need to implement POP (Post Office Protocol) either natively (not recommended) or through a library. e.g. if you were using java, http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/75016/Retrieving-email-using-Java-POP-Library might be a good resource.

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Again, you'd need SMTP for outgoing emails. Hope the above two links lead to more pointers.

Comment: I am using javamail for android. Did i need a permission for using it?

Comment: No you didn't need permission if you're building an email reader app. I'm pretty sure it won't be allowed if you're using it to spam.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using SMTP/IMAP and no licensed API from Google, there is no reason you need the permission of Google.

You should look at the Terms and Conditions though. You might find something saying you are not supposed to use the service with mailing robots like you did, and that they may delete your account or sue you.

Comment: No, i didn't find something at terms and conditions not to use mailing robots.